# Why does Python petl return the following exception: "TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()"

Tags: python

While running the following code:

```
import petl
data = [{'one': 'foo', 1: 'bar'}]
table = petl.fromdicts(data)
print(table)
```

I encountered the following exception:

```
...
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\petl\io\json.py", line 132, in __iter__
    hdr = sorted(hdr)
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `petl` package attempts to sort dictionary headers during loading. Due to the mixture of `str` and `int` headers, the sort cannot complete. `petl`, therefore, does not support mixed-type headers where the headers are not comparable during a sort.

To solve this problem, convert all headers to `str`, convert all headers to `int`, or ensure that all headers may be compared to each other during a sort.